# Sending data to a php server

Tags: java, php, android

What i would like to do, is to send data to a php server but without visiting the site
or using a browser.
 Normally in a browser it is somethink like this:

**/test/index.php?name1=value1&name2=value2**

I would like to send name1=value1&name2=value2 to the server using Android(Java).

Both POST or GET work for me.

Comment: Is there actually a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this through something like:

```
final HttpGet uri = new HttpGet("http://example.com/test/index.php?name1=value1");
final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uri);
```

Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at HttpRequest:
http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android

In tutorial where there is: key1 and value1 that acts same as: $_POST['key1'] == "value1".

Also you will need to use AsyncTask since you cannot run network tasks on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be using [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (see [this article](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for more information).

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("/test/index.php?key="+ + URLEncoder.encode(value);

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```